# Sprite faces in the direction you press

Tags: java, sprite, lwjgl

I am fairly new to Java and LWJGL. I am trying to make a 2d sprite change appearance so it faces in the direction that you are holding, how would I go about this?

So far I have this-

```
package keyboardinputdb;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class KeyboardInputDB extends JFrame{

//Variables
int x, y, scoreCount;

private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg; 

Image littleAdventurer;
boolean faceLeft;
boolean faceRight;
boolean faceUp;

Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18);

//Action Listener
public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == e.VK_LEFT){
            x-=3;
            if(x <= 0){
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT){
            x+=3;
            if(x >= 235){
                x = 235;
            }
        }
        if(keyCode == e.VK_UP){
            y-=3;
            if(y <= 20){
                y = 20;
            }
        }
        if(keyCode == e.VK_DOWN){
            y+=3;
            if(y >= 235){
                y = 235;
            }
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

    }
}

public KeyboardInputDB(){
    //Load Images
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Clive/Documents/NetBeansProjects/KeyboardInput with DB/src/keyboardinputdb/littleAdventurer.gif");
    littleAdventurer = i.getImage();

    //Game Properties
    addKeyListener(new KeyboardInputDB.AL());
    setTitle("Java Game");
    setSize(600, 500);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    x = 150;
    y = 150;
    scoreCount = 0;
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Score: " + scoreCount, 450, 70);

    if(faceLeft = true){
        g.drawImage(littleAdventurer, x, y, this);
    }
    else{
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
    }

    repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyboardInputDB javagame = new KeyboardInputDB();
}
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your main problem is that you're using jFrame instead of LWJGL. I would recommend that you change to LWJGL first. You're also using three boolean variables for which direction your sprite is facing. What happens when both faceLeft and faceRight are true? You should use enums instead.

I assume you're new to Java, so I'll give you a little tutorial in enums...

1st, add this to the top of your class where you declare your varaibles:

```
public static enum Direction{
      UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
}
public static Direction direction = Direction.DOWN;
```

You can now use this code to check if an enum is a certain value:

```
if(direction == Direction.LEFT){
    //Do something.
}
```

You can also set an enum simply by calling:

```
direction = Direction.RIGHT;
```

And even easier way to check an enum's vause is by using a switch statement:

```
switch(direction){
    case UP:
        //Do something when up.
        break;
    case DOWN:
        //Do something when down.
        break;
    case LEFT:
        //Do something when left.
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        //Do something when right.
        break;
}
```

This best way that I can describe an enum to beginners is similar to a boolean (where it has a limited amount of options) but you can make as many options as you want.

Your current system also isn't using LWJGL, so I recommend changing to that if that's what you would like to use. Making a game is much easier with LWJGL than jFrame once you learn how to use OpenGL.

This page will prove useful: http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Getting_started

Just made quads first, then you can easily learn how to add a sprite in and rotate it using glRotatef()